# R Shiny error: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, shiny

My attempt to build my first simple shiny app has run into a frustrating error message. Upon running the code below, my shiny app loads, but the mainPanel displays the error message:

> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Unfortunately I cannot debug this, because RStudio doesn't tell me which line is causing the error. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
require(shiny)
require(dplyr)

ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("NFL"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("Margin", "Current margin", min=-50, max=50, value=0, step=1),
    numericInput("Spread", "Spread", value=0, width="30%"),
    radioButtons("Quarter", "Current period", choices=c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "OT"), 
                 selected = "1st", inline = TRUE,width = NULL),
    textInput("TimeRemaining", "Time remaining (mm:ss)", value="15:00",  width="30%"),
    radioButtons("Down", "Down", choices=c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "N/A"), inline = TRUE),
    numericInput("YTG", "Yards to go", value=10,  width="30%"),
    numericInput("YFOG", "Yards from own goal", value=50,  width="30%"),
    radioButtons("Timeouts_Off", "Timeouts: Offense", choices=c("1", "2", "3")),
    radioButtons("Timeouts_Def", "Timeouts: Defence", choices=c("1", "2", "3"))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput('testTable')
  )
)

server=function(input, output){
  out <- reactive({
    x=matrix(0, nrow=1, ncol=11)
    colnames(x)=c("mar", "timeRemaining", "dwn.1", "dwn.2", "dwn.3", "dwn.4", "ytg","yfog", "closingLine", "timo", "timd")

    qtr=switch(input$Quarter, "1st"=1, "2nd"=2,"3rd"=3,"4th"=4, "OT"=5)
    mins=as.numeric(substr(input$TimeRemaining,1,2))
    secs=as.numeric(substr(input$TimeRemaining,4,5))
    timeLeft=100-10/6*((4-qtr)*15+(mins+secs/60))

    x[1,1]=input$Margin
    x[1,2]=timeLeft
    x[1,3]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=1, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=0,"4th"=0)
    x[1,4]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=1,"3rd"=0,"4th"=0)
    x[1,5]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=1,"4th"=0)
    x[1,6]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=0,"4th"=1)
    x[1,7]=input$YTG
    x[1,8]=input$YFOG
    x[1,9]=input$Spread
    x[1,10]=as.numeric(input$Timeouts_Off)
    x[1,11]=as.numeric(input$Timeouts_Def)

    x=data.frame(x)

    xsq=select(x,mar:timd, -dwn.1, -dwn.2, -dwn.3, -dwn.4)^2
    colnames(xsq)=paste(colnames(xsq), "sq",  sep = "_")

    xln=log(select(x,timeRemaining:timd, -closingLine, -dwn.1, -dwn.2, -dwn.3, -dwn.4)+1)
    colnames(xln)=paste(colnames(xln), "ln",  sep = "_")
    x=cbind(x, xsq, xln)

    print(x)
    rm(xln, xsq)
  })
  output$testTable <- renderDataTable(out())
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple changes required in server, ui is okay, the following should work:

```
server=function(input, output){

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- NULL

  newEntry <- observe({ # use observe pattern

    x=as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=1, ncol=11))
    colnames(x)=c("mar", "timeRemaining", "dwn.1", "dwn.2", "dwn.3", "dwn.4", "ytg","yfog", "closingLine", "timo", "timd")

    qtr=switch(input$Quarter, "1st"=1, "2nd"=2,"3rd"=3,"4th"=4, "OT"=5)
    mins=as.numeric(substr(input$TimeRemaining,1,2))
    secs=as.numeric(substr(input$TimeRemaining,4,5))
    timeLeft=100-10/6*((4-qtr)*15+(mins+secs/60))

    x[1,1]=input$Margin
    x[1,2]=timeLeft
    x[1,3]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=1, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=0,"4th"=0)
    x[1,4]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=1,"3rd"=0,"4th"=0)
    x[1,5]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=1,"4th"=0)
    x[1,6]=switch(input$Down, "1st"=0, "2nd"=0,"3rd"=0,"4th"=1)
    x[1,7]=input$YTG
    x[1,8]=input$YFOG
    x[1,9]=input$Spread # wrong case earlier
    x[1,10]=as.numeric(input$Timeouts_Off) # need to be converted to numeric
    x[1,11]=as.numeric(input$Timeouts_Def) # need to be converted to numeric

    #xsq=select(x,mar:timd, -dwn.1, -dwn.2, -dwn.3, -dwn.4)^2 # deplyr::select was not working
    xsq <- x[-3:-6]
    colnames(xsq)=paste(colnames(xsq), "sq",  sep = "_")
    #xln=log(select(x,timeRemaining:timd, -closingLine, -dwn.1, -dwn.2, -dwn.3, -dwn.4)) # need to handle log properly
    xln=x[-c(3:6,9)]
    indices= which(xln!=0)
    if (length(indices)>0) {
      xln[indices]=log(xln[indices])
    }
    colnames(xln)=paste(colnames(xln), "ln",  sep = "_")
    x=cbind(x, xsq, xln)
    rm(xln, xsq)
    isolate(values$df <- x)
  })

  output$testTable <- renderDataTable({values$df})
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo error for the variable Spread. Change

```
x[1,9]=input$spread
```

to

```
x[1,9]=input$Spread
```

I deduced this by inserting a `print(x)` in between each line of code, which helped me in printing the value of x on the R-console. The value of variable Spread, even when I changed in the shiny app, did not change the value of x. Hence that itself suggested that there is something wrong with Spread, which is typo.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**  Add follwoing at the end of `out() function`

```
print(x)
rm(xln, xsq)
x
```

The problem is that you are not returning anything from the `out` function.

Comment: Thank you. Have fixed the typo. I am still not able to get the x matrix into the output table though - do you know why not?

Comment: You are using a function `select`, which I have no idea about. That is the source of error. From where does you get this function?

Comment: it is from the dplyr package (which i have now added a require() line for in the code. it shouldn't cause an error anymore.

Comment: did you try using the modified code above? I made some changes